# How can my MySQL query giving the rank of all games just give the rank of each players top game?

Tags: mysql, ranking, rank

```
SELECT 
1+(SELECT count(*) from games a WHERE a.score > g.score) as rank,
score, p.leaderboard_initials, p.operating_system
FROM games g
inner join players p on (p.google_id = g.google_id)
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Returns a leaderboard featuring EVERY game for a player.

[image]

I need to return a leaderboard of where only the BEST scoring game of each player is listed.  So `44rhh` would still be on top, followed by `DMC` but then `BMO` would be in third place.

I know the solution should be easy but I just can't think how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could select max score group by leaderboard_initials

you could select max score group by leaderboard_initials

```
set @rank=0;
select (@rank:=@rank+1) rank , leaderboard_initials, max(score)  max_score  
from  (
    SELECT 
    1+(SELECT count(*) 
    from games a WHERE a.score > g.score) as rank,
    score, p.leaderboard_initials, p.operating_system
    FROM games g
    inner join players p on (p.google_id = g.google_id)
    ORDER BY score DESC
    LIMIT 0, 100;
) t  
group by leaderboard_initials 
order by max_score DESC
```

Comment: Thanks this is almost right but here the rank of BMO would be 4 whereas it should be 3.  Any ideas how to tweak it?

Comment: explain better i don't uderstand you comment

Comment: I need the third player, BMO to have rank 3. Desired rank in red here  https://ibb.co/vdbgYJy

Comment: @DaveChambers  answer  updated with calculated rank